Can Excel throttle cell updates?
I'm developing a plugin to relay updates from a pub/sub cache into an Excel workbook hosted within office365. Update frequency can be very high (upto thousands of updates a second). Is there a guard within Excel to protect itself from bursty data, in the same vein as Application.RTD.ThrottleInterval?
Thanks!
